# How to get a Django ModelForm to redirect to another ModelForm on submit?

Tags: django, forms, validation, redirect

I have a template which displays a certain `ModelForm` at one of the URLs of my Django site. The `ModelForm` is based on a model with two fields,

```
class ActionCode(models.Model):
    action_code = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10,
                                   verbose_name="Action Code")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('action_code',)
```

I would like my `ModelForm` to give the user only the first field (Action Code), then when it is submitted, verify if the value entered already exists or not. If it doesn't already exist, I want to redirect the user to be able to enter a Description for that Action Code (the second field in my model). So I wrote a second `ModelForm` which uses the Description field of the model, and I would like my first form to redirect to the second form after validating that the data is new. Ideally then, the Description would be linked to this specific piece of data and both would go into the same Django database table (hence them coming from the same model). However, when I enter a new piece of data and hit Submit, the site simply stays at the /action_code/ URL and displays a Submit button, and nothing else. How do I get the first form to redirect to the second form, and what is the best way to make sure it only does so if the data is new?

Here are my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^action_code/', action_code_form, name="actioncode"),
url(r'descr_form/', code_description_form, name='description'),
```

Here are my two forms in `forms.py':

```
class ActionCodeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActionCode
        fields = ('action_code',)


class ActionCodeDescriptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActionCode
        fields = ('description',)
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def action_code_form(request):
    form = ActionCodeForm()
    description_form = ActionCodeDescriptionForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            action_code = form.cleaned_data['action_code']
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'description_form.html',
                          {'form': description_form})
    return render(request, 'action_code_form.html', {'form': form})


def code_description_form(request):
    form = ActionCodeDescriptionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionCodeDescriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'description_form.html', {'descr_form': form})
```

And my templates:

action_code_form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

description_form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ descr_form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms don't redirect to anything. It's the view's responsibility to do the redirect.

You need two views, with two URLs; when the first form submission is successful, the view should redirect to the second URL.